# Join with SubString

Tags: sql, join, mariadb, substring

I am trying to select some records based on joining two tables with partially matching fields.

Take a table (people) that looks something like this:

```
peopleID poeopleStatus BuidlingIDRoomID Sender  DateTimeStamp
    1       A           ABQ-203          XX     2023-10-01 10:00:00
    2       Q           BC-203           AO     2023-01-01 11:00:00
    3       N           AB-201           CC     2023-02-01 12:00:00
    4       B           AA-111           BB     2023-03-01 13:00:00
    5       B           CA-111           BC     2023-03-01 14:00:00
```

and a table (buildinglocations) like:

```
BuildingID  Owner
AA          Santa
AB          Banta
BC          Satan
```

I am using the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT people.*, buildings.*
FROM `people`
LEFT JOIN buildinglocations
  ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(people.buildingIDRoomID, '-', 1) -1) = buildinglocations.buildingID
WHERE `peoplestatus` = 'N' AND Sender = 'CC' AND Owner = 'Banta'
ORDER BY people.`DateTimeStamp` ASC
```

This might not be relevant, but, I get n records in phpmyadmin and n+2 when running same sql query in the php script. In fact there are exactly 2 records which should not appear in the php script. In phpmyadmin I also get the following multiple times below the query result.

> Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '-'

I am not even sure if the above is a valid SQL statement, so let's start from there.

TIA

**Edit:**  The SQL statement was incorrect because as @paul-spiegel pointed the SUBSTRING_INDEX parameters were in the wrong order.  Also, I realized I didn't need LEFT.

Comment: If you have to use functions in the JOIN conditions, it usually indicates a poor table design.

Comment: We are a startup - these are completely unanticipated use cases in a new, innovative product. Please help with an answer.

Comment: All the better, then you now have the opportunity to do it right from the start!

Comment: @jarlh the product is live for the last two years - this is a *new unanticipated use case*.  If you can help, please do...

Comment: Add a tag for the dbms you're using, to get better attention. (Product specific functions used.)

Comment: Your parameters for SUBSTRING_INDEX are in wrong order.

Comment: Yes, I was just going to correct that.  I think the corrected solution works.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT people.*, buildinglocations.Owner
FROM people
LEFT JOIN buildinglocations ON LEFT(people.BuidlingIDRoomID, 2) = buildinglocations.BuildingID
WHERE people.peopleStatus = 'N' AND people.Sender = 'CC' AND buildinglocations.Owner = 'Banta'
ORDER BY people.DateTimeStamp ASC;
```

Comment: LEFT(people.BuidlingIDRoomID, 2) won't work by itself, because people.BuidlingIDRoomID could two, three or even more characters.  I will edit the question to demonstrate.